# Impossible to get inline form labels to work inside InfoWindow

Tags: jquery, css, forms, google-maps, label

I'm going crazy with this. I tried every possible solution found on the web (which seems to work for everyone) but none of it seems to work, because I want it inside a Google Maps InfoWindow.

The InfoWindow content is loaded via Ajax, so I'm no really sure where to put the Jquery bit - although I have tried (I think!) every possible combination.

Solutions tried: 
[Making Awesome Form’s Inline Labels with jQuery](http://www.narga.net/making-awesome-forms-inline-labels-with-jquery/), [jQuery Inline Form Labels](http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-inline-form-labels/),  [Awesome Inline Form Labels](http://zurb.com/playground/inline-form-labels)  and others...

The only thing that works is HTML5's `placeholder` but I'm not happy about this because it doesn't work very well below IE10.

Here is a snapshot of the desired effect:

[image]

I would like this to work inside this InfoWindow below. See the text "Nome opcional"? I'd like it to be an inline blurred label, like the picture above.

[image]

This is the code used to load the InfoWindow contents:

```
function load_newinfowindow_content(lat, long, infowindow){
    $.ajax({
    url: site_root +'map/newmarker_infowindow/'+lat+'/'+long,
    success: function(data){
      infowindow.setContent(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The infoWindow is basic HTML form. The CSS is global for all pages, including the InfoWindow (and it works fine).

```
<form name="newMark" id="newMark" method=post action="<?php echo base_url();?>map/new_marker">
<input type=hidden name=latitude value="<?php echo $lat;?>"><input type=hidden name=longitude value="<?php echo $long;?>">
Deseja criar uma nova marcação aqui?
<label for="name">Nome opcional</label>
<input class="text name" type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sim">
```

I have already tried placing the JQuery's `ready` code inside the InfoWindow HTML and "outside" on the calling page. Neither works.
Any hints on why this should not work inside an InfoWindow?

Comment: The code is kinda big for each of the solutions, that's why I added the links. But I'll add one of them to serve as an example and a snapshot of the desired effect.

Comment: What does your code look like to render the infowindow?  Jquery probably expect it to be in the DOM before it executes, perhaps run the jquery code in the "domready" event on the infowindow (after it has been rendered and added to the DOM).

Comment: I have added the code to load the InfoWindow and its HTML content. By DOM ready you mean `$(document).ready` right? As I added in the question details, I have tried placing it an possible places. I only get "partial" results, but never the label inside the text field.

Comment: you wrote `By DOM ready you mean $(document).ready`. No.  The domready event on the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

Comment: Got it working! It's not as pretty as the suggested solutions but it worked. Domready didn't work, because it was called as soon as the InfoWindow opened, and I have a gif running while the ajax loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!
By trying to place the Javascript code in different places, and as suggested in the comments, even tried to use the `domready` event of the InfoWindow, I found the only place it really works.

Inside my AJAX call to load the content, and it became like this:

```
function load_newinfowindow_content(lat, long, infowindow){
    $.ajax({
    url: site_root +'map/newmarker_infowindow/'+lat+'/'+long,
    success: function(data){
      infowindow.setContent(data);
      processInLineLabels();
    }
  });
}
```

And the `$( document ).ready(function()` which is present in all solutions for this to work I turned into a function, like the one below (but it should work for other as well).

```
function processInLineLabels() {
  $('input[title]').each(function() {
      if($(this).val() === '') {
         $(this).val($(this).attr('title')); 
      }

   $(this).focus(function() {
      if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
         $(this).val('').addClass('focused');  
      }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
       if($(this).val() === '') {
           $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).removeClass('focused');  
       }
     });
 });
}
```